# Evaluate html as a String containing <% %> tags with scripts

Tags: javascript, java, html, string, escaping

I have maybe a trivial problem in my code wherein I am getting an HTML as response from a web service which is being returned as a java String. I want to display this String as HTML on the webpage. The issue I am facing is that the html retured contains some scripts in the form of

```
<% ... %>
```

tags. These are being displayed as is on the webpage. All I want is that these to be evaluated right away and not being displayed as text on the screen.
For example, The text that is being displayed is

```
<% if('a' == 'b'){ %>
```

Hello a.

I want to get rid of the <% ... %> thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're getting JSP sources not plain HTML so I'd check why this is so (this is probably not intended). Otherwise you could either look for `<%` or `%>` and display an error or remove that using a regular expression (e.g. `String.replaceAll("<%.*?%>","")`). The problem with JSP code is that the HTML structure might change depending on how those tags are evaluated and thus just removing them might not result in what you want to get.

Comment: @Thomas - Yes, that is right. Every time the tags may evaluate differently, so it would not be a wise thing to remove those tags. Can the JSP code be evaluated on runtime, every time?

Comment: Well you can feed the JSP code to a JSP engine to get it evaluated but since it seems to originate from a 3rd party server I'm not sure it would be a wise move. Even if you'd not consider security risks (do you completely trust _all_ the code you get from that server?) you might run into issues of classes not being present on the current classpath, data missing etc. I'd rather let the server evaluate the JSP and return plain html (or, if you like, JSON or XML) only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want to delete these things from a Java String, so something like this could work :

```
String code = "<html> Hello<% if('a' == 'b'){ %>, I'm<% if('a' == 'b'){ %> French</html>";
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    String str = "";

    end = code.indexOf("<%",start); //First substring will do "0 - end";

    while(end != -1 && start != -1){
        str += code.substring(start, end);

        start = code.indexOf("%>",end) +2; //+2 is used to get the index after "%>"
        end = code.indexOf("<%",start); //First occurence of "<%" after the last "%>"
    }

    str += code.substring(start,code.length());//Last substring will do "start - str.len-1"

    System.out.println(str);
```

Simpler way

```
    String code = "<html>Hello<% if('a' == 'b'){ %>, I'm<% if('a' == 'b'){ %> French</html>";
    String str = code.replaceAll("<%.*?%>", "");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Prints

```
<html>Hello, I'm French</html>
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want. Read my comment above to understand the scenario. I want dynamic evaluation of the JSP code. Different conditions will display different html on the page.